# how to load a big picture or swf file by calling Loader.load() in Flex, and make the container adjust the size of the loading content?

Tags: apache-flex, size, loader

I get a ActionScript class for loading the content:

public class LoaderContainer extends Sprite {

```
    public function LoaderExample() {
        loader = new Loader();      
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        addChild(loader);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("File://C:/1.swf");
        loader.load(request);
    }
    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        Alert.show(this.x+"/"+this.y+"/"+this.width +"/"+ this.height);
    }
```

}

And then add the LoaderContainer to a Panel control in main MXML.

What supprise me is that the LoaderContainer's width/height is changing all the way according to the contents that it loaded.

Is there any way that we can limit the content's size right obeying the container's size?

Thanks 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Flex, is there any reason why you wouldn't just load it directly into an mx:Image or mx:SWFLoader?  Since you're loading it and using addChild it's not being wrangled into the Flex framework where you could control it...

```
<mx:Image source="File://C:/1.swf" width="100" height="100" />
```